# Shortcode / WP_Query in post changes context

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, shortcode

We have a shortcode that causes WP_Query to be executed, retrieving an instance of a custom post type. In our single.php this changes the context (after the call to the_content()) from the original post (with the shortcode in it) to that of the custom post retrieved.

I spotted this because the comments template wasn't displaying, as the comment_status on the custom post is 'closed' - what we're interested in, however, is that the comment_status on the original post is 'open'.

Is this an error in the execution of our shortcode/custom post type, is there a way of doing this that won't mess up what happens in single.php?

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after a secondary query to restore the global `$post` to its original context.